# spawnしたtelnet プロセスに対して英数字以外のキー（Controlキー + ]など）を送るには

Tags: bash, expect

spawn した telnet プロセスに対して、文字以外のキーを送る場合、どうすればいいでしょうか。

例えば、文字"START"を送る場合、下記コードのように記述しました。
同様に、"hoge"の部分で 「ctrl と ] と retern」 など、英数字以外のキーを含ませたい場合は、どう記述するものなのでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 10.0.0.1 50001
expect "SCPI" { sleep 1; send "START"; }
expect "SCPI" { sleep 1; send "hoge"; }
expect eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えばC-cを送信したい場合

```
send "\003";
```

でできます。
その他のエスケープシーケンスについては[ASCII character table](http://foldoc.org/ASCII+character+table)を参照いただけるとわかるかと思います。

あるいは

```
send "^[";
```

と書くのですが、 `^[` この文字を普通の打つのではなく、vimであればinsert modeで`C-v C-[`とすることで制御文字を入力しても可能だと思います。Emacsでは`C-q C-[`です

Answer (score 1):

spawn した telnet プロセスに対して ^] を送信したいのであれば、以下のようにエスケープすれば制御コードを送信できます。

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet localhost 50001
expect "SCPI" {
    sleep 1
    send "START"
}
expect "SCPI" {
    sleep 1
    send "\035"
}
expect "telnet>" {
    send "quit\r"
}
expect eof
```

エスケープの方法は以下に記載されています。

http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q54